# TortoiseGit - right click on file to commit just that file?

Tags: tortoise-git

TortoiseGit uses a [Windows Explorer] context-menu "Git commit -> master" to commit changes.

Is it possible to configure this so that by default it only commits the file you right-clicked on (when opening the context menu), instead of all modified files in the repository?

i.e. in a directory with lots of changes, we don't want to "select none" and then find our one file in the "Changes made" list, given that we already 'chose' that file in the Explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just basing this answer on information found [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html#tgit-automation-basics), but you'll have to try it and get back to me:

1. Find out where **TortoiseGitProc.exe** is located
2. Save the following as a .REG file after editing in the proper path to the EXE (don't mess up the double backslashes!), then double-click to merge into your registry:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\commit]
   @="Comm&it"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\commit\command]
   @="\"C:\\Path\\to\\TortoiseGitProc.exe\" /command:commit /path:\"%1\" /logmsg:\"Committing single file\" /closeonend:0"
   ```
3. Right-click any file, click on **Commit** and see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open the TortoiseGit "Settings" screen
Open the "General/Dialogs 2" menu
Find the "Commit" section
Uncheck the "Select items automatically" option
Click "Apply"
Click "Ok"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).